# Bootstrap v5.2 Custom button does not have color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm attempting to create a custom button class within Bootstrap where the color is a iris-purple.

I used Sass to generate said button variant:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$mynewcolor:#5D3FD3;

.btn-purple {
  @include button-variant($mynewcolor, shade-color($mynewcolor, 7.5%), shade-color($mynewcolor, 10%), tint-color($mynewcolor,5%), tint-color($mynewcolor, 10%), shade-color($mynewcolor,30%));
}
```

Which compiled to this:

```
.btn-purple {
  --bs-btn-color: #5439be;
  --bs-btn-bg: #5D3FD3;
  --bs-btn-border-color: #563ac3;
  --bs-btn-hover-color: #261762;
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6f54d8;
  --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #8068dd;
  --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: 86, 58, 194;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #000;
  --bs-btn-active-bg: #7d65dc;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #674ec9;
  --bs-btn-active-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  --bs-btn-disabled-color: #fff;
  --bs-btn-disabled-bg: #5D3FD3;
  --bs-btn-disabled-border-color: #563ac3;
}
```

I attempted to use it in HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-purple btn-lg" type="button">Example button</button>
```

But no color:
[image]

My Firefox inspector does not show `btn-purple` as a CSS class in use on the page. Is there a step I missed?

Comment: Clear the browser cache and reload the page

Comment: @ArleighHix this did not solve the issue

Comment: If the `.btn-purple` styles are in the compiled .css file then your browser is not loading the current version of the file

Answer (score 0):

I think, there might be a problem linking the Sass file to your HTML file. make sure that you have linked it before the Bootstrap CSS file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you asking me to recompile the .scss file?

Answer (score 0):

Try darken & lighten in your button-variant

```
$mynewcolor:#5D3FD3;
        
.btn-purple {
    @include button-variant($mynewcolor, darken($mynewcolor, 7.5%), darken($mynewcolor, 10%), lighten($mynewcolor,5%), lighten($mynewcolor, 10%), darken($mynewcolor,30%));
}
```